# CatalogInvenotry Stock Item save

Tags: model, stock, ee-1.13.1.0

I found that `CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item` model doesn't trigger `_beforeSave()` method of it's parent. So, we cannot observe models save_before event. Is it special for preventing from hooks or some bug? Do it leads to some problems or nor if I add `parent::_saveBefore()` line within the method.

```
class Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
      //here should be parent::_saveBefore() call by Magento logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a bug and have reported it as such years ago. Previously the following line was included

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before', array('item' => $this));
```

to make up for the missing parent::_saveBefore(). See [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.3/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php#L457).

I would suggest re-instating that line if you want to observe the before save event.